# Add a runnable thread inside an Async Task for splash screen delay

Tags: android

Hi I wanted to add a delay on my splash screen using a Async Task but I can't figure out how should I do it. Here's my DoInBackground code so far:

```
@Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

            Thread SplashThread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            int waited = 0;
                            while(running && (waited < delayTime)) {
                                sleep(100);
                                if(running) {
                                    waited += 100;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                            // do nothing
                        } finally {
                            finish();
                            stop();
                        }
                    }
                };
                SplashThread.start();

            return null;
        }
```

I think the part of the return null is the main cause of problem since it's ending up my Async Task even my SplashThread is still running in background leaving a leak on thins part onwards which lead to error. I also tried to use counDownTimer as a subtitute but this leads in the same problem. Any ways to do this properly?

Comment: There is no need to create a thread in an `AsyncTask` which already is running on its own thread. You could have the same while loop in the `doInBackground` before you return. Although I don't see the real need for the while loop. You'll do your work in the `doInBackground` method and then simply return and kill the splash. If you want to add extra delay(I don't see why you would want to do this) you could add a `Thread.sleep(time)` before returning.from `doInBackground`.

Comment: It works! but returning some errors Activity com.android.test.SplashScreen has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4117fa70 that was originally added here.

Comment: Got it already. Well it's something on my part since I'm displaying an activity without destroying the SplashScreen Activity. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: If you want I can write my comment as an answer, if you want the question to become answered:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the additional thread that you start in the `doInBackground` method of your `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` itself runs the `doInBackground` method in another thread, also, 
because of this the `while` loop it's most likely unnecessary. Do the work you want to do in the `doInBackground` method and then simply return. If you want/need some additional delay(although you should avoid this at all costs) you can use the `Thread.sleep` method to pause the thread before returning.